# Glassfish/Struts Web application: Can't locate reason for thrown IOException

Tags: java, postgresql, struts2, glassfish

I have a Java web application that throws an IOException (Connection is closed). Unfortunately, I can not locate the reason/source of the problem (hence, I can not provide a minimal code sample). I can not reproduce the exception in the development environment, in the production environment it is thrown regularly (eg 50 logged-in users: thrown (on average) every 10 to 20 minutes, sometimes more often).

How can I identify the reason for this problem (it seems that it is related to the used libraries, maybe some configuration problem)?

Here are the settings:

- Java application using Struts 2 and JDBC (Postgres 9), libraries:

  - asm-5.0.2.jar
  - asm-commons-5.0.2.jar
  - asm-tree-5.0.2.jar
  - commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
  - commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
  - commons-digester-2.0.jar
  - commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar
  - commons-io-2.2.jar
  - commons-lang-2.4.jar
  - commons-lang3-3.2.jar
  - commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
  - freemarker-2.3.22.jar
  - javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
  - javax.servlet-api.jar (version 3.1.0)
  - junit-4.7.jar
  - ognl-3.0.6.jar
  - ojdbc14.jar
  - postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc41.jar
  - struts2-core-2.3.24.1.jar
  - struts2-tiles-plugin-2.3.24.1.jar
  - tiles-api-2.0.6.jar
  - tiles-core-2.0.6.jar
  - tiles-jsp-2.0.6.jar
  - xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar
- Deployed on Glassfish server 4.1.1

Here is the stack trace:

```
 [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [[
      StandardWrapperValve[default]: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
    java.io.IOException: Connection is closed
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOConnection.assertOpen(NIOConnection.java:432)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:653)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:355)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:342)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:161)
            at org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.copy(DefaultServlet.java:2199)
            at org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.serveResource(DefaultServlet.java:1085)
            at org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:568)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
            at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:96)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:413)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Locally closed
    ]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Regarding the database access, the code uses JDBC (postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc41.jar) with driver name org.postgresql.Driver. This should be unrelated to grizzly/glassfish, since it does not use a connection pool configured in glassfish but a custom one.
Are you sure this is related to JDBC connections? My impression is that it is related to HTTP connections established to/from the clients that access the web application.

Comment: You're definitely right, it's a network connection. Please post the libraries (with version) you are using

Comment: I added the complete list of used libraries + versions to the original post.

Comment: Is your production setup uses SSL and developement environment on non SSL configuration ?

Comment: Are you using tiles 2 or 3? 3 has another plugin

Comment: SSL is enabled both in the development and production environment.

Comment: tiles 2 (tiles.xml is specified with:

<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">

...

Comment: any update on this ? as I have the same issue but with some web sockets. The thing is that when this occurs the app start to works slow and the load on DB increases exponentially.